# How to check if the values extracted from image is already exist in a txt or csv file in python?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, file-handling, python-tesseract

I am working on OCR using python with pytesseract. So exactly what i am trying to do is to read the text on image, extract the text and store the extracted text in a txt or csv file using file handling. 
I want multiple files to be read, store the text and perform a check if the image's text im going to get read and store is already exist in a txt file.
Here is my code that is working without any error. The last lines are what i was trying to do but doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me out regarding this?
Thanks in advance.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract,csv,re,os
from PIL import Image
from ast import literal_eval

img = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("test1.png"), lang="eng")
print(img)

with open('C:\\Users\\Hasan\\Videos\\Captures\\saved.csv', "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(img)

string = open('C:\\Users\\Hasan\\Videos\\Captures\\saved.csv').read()
new_str = re.sub('[^a-zA-z0-9\n\.]', ' ', string)
open('C:\\Users\\Hasan\\Videos\\Captures\\saved.csv', "w").write(new_str)

# f = open("saved.csv", "r")
# read = f.readline()
# print("\n" + f.read())

with open('C:\\Users\\Hasan\\Videos\\Captures\\saved.csv') as sv:
    for line in sv:
        if img in line:
            print("Data already exists")
        else:
            print("file saved successfully")
```

Comment: This is happening because when you are writing ```new_str``` it will create a new row whenever it encounters new line character. So while iterating it in the last step you get only the first line of the text in ```line```, whereas ```img``` contains entire extracted text.

Answer (score 3):

Replace '\n' while writing to the CSV file and strip '\n' from `img` while comparing.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract,csv,re,os
from PIL import Image
from ast import literal_eval
img_path = "example_01.png"
out_csv_path = "saved.csv"
img = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(img_path), lang="eng")
print(img)

with open(out_csv_path, "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(img)

string = open(out_csv_path).read()
new_str = re.sub('[^a-zA-z0-9\. ]', '', string)
open(out_csv_path, "w").write(new_str)

# f = open("saved.csv", "r")
# read = f.readline()
# print("\n" + f.read())

with open(out_csv_path,newline='') as sv:
    img = re.sub('[^a-zA-z0-9\. ]', '', img)
    for line in sv:
        print("Line text is: {}\nExtracted Text is: {}".format(line,img))
        if img in line:
            print("Data already exists")
        else:
            print("file saved successfully")
```

Sample output:

```
Noisyimage
to test
Tesseract OCR
Line text is: Noisyimageto testTesseract OCR
Extracted Text is: Noisyimageto testTesseract OCR
Data already exists
```

Comment: Thankyou Satheesh K. there is minor mistake which is whenever i delete the file and try to save the data by running the code it prints "Data already exists"? Codes seems fine to me tho?